# Why does installing LAME fail?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, ffmpeg

I want to install ffmpeg with mp3lame enabled following [this tutorial](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9868359&postcount=1289). In step 2, I get the error

> libfaac is not found

and in step 5, installing lame is giving the error in the log below.
Why does it fail? What do I have to do?

```
reach121@youngib:~/lame-3.98.4$ sudo checkinstall --pkgname=lame-ffmpeg --pkgversion="3.98.4" --backup=no --default     --deldoc=yes

checkinstall 1.6.2, Copyright 2009 Felipe Eduardo Sanchez Diaz Duran
           This software is released under the GNU GPL.



*****************************************
**** Debian package creation selected ***
*****************************************

This package will be built according to these values:

0 -  Maintainer: [ root@youngib ]
1 -  Summary: [ Package created with checkinstall 1.6.2 ]
2 -  Name:    [ lame-ffmpeg ]
3 -  Version: [ 3.98.4 ]
4 -  Release: [ 1 ]
5 -  License: [ GPL ]
6 -  Group:   [ checkinstall ]
7 -  Architecture: [ amd64 ]
8 -  Source location: [ lame-3.98.4 ]
9 -  Alternate source location: [  ]
10 - Requires: [  ]
11 - Provides: [ lame-ffmpeg ]
12 - Conflicts: [  ]
13 - Replaces: [  ]

Enter a number to change any of them or press ENTER to continue:

Installing with make install...

========================= Installation results ===========================
Making install in mpglib
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/mpglib'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/mpglib'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/mpglib'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/mpglib'
Making install in libmp3lame
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/libmp3lame'
Making install in i386
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/libmp3lame/i386'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/libmp3lame/i386'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/libmp3lame/i386'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/libmp3lame/i386'
Making install in vector
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/libmp3lame/vector'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/libmp3lame/vector'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/libmp3lame/vector'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/libmp3lame/vector'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/libmp3lame'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/libmp3lame'
test -z "/usr/local/lib" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/lib"
 /bin/bash ../libtool --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c  'libmp3lame.la' '/usr/local/lib/libmp3lame.la'
/usr/bin/install -c .libs/libmp3lame.lai /usr/local/lib/libmp3lame.la
/usr/bin/install -c .libs/libmp3lame.a /usr/local/lib/libmp3lame.a
chmod 644 /usr/local/lib/libmp3lame.a
ranlib /usr/local/lib/libmp3lame.a
PATH="$PATH:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/local/lib
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,--rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/libmp3lame'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/libmp3lame'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/libmp3lame'
Making install in frontend
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/frontend'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/frontend'
test -z "/usr/local/bin" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/bin"
  /bin/bash ../libtool --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c 'lame' '/usr/local/bin/lame'
/usr/bin/install -c lame /usr/local/bin/lame
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/frontend'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/frontend'
Making install in Dll
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/Dll'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/Dll'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/Dll'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/Dll'
Making install in debian
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/debian'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/debian'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/debian'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/debian'
Making install in doc
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/doc'
Making install in html
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/doc/html'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/doc/html'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
test -z "/usr/local/share/doc/lame/html" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/share/doc/lame/html"
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/share/doc': No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [install-pkghtmlDATA] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/doc/html'
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/doc/html'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/reach121/lame-3.98.4/doc'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

Cleaning up...OK

Bye.

reach121@youngib:~/lame-3.98.4$
```

Comment: Not even remotely appropriate question for SF, moving to SU.

Comment: That is the strangest error... usually it's a sign of forgetting to use "-p" in the mkdir command.  Can you try running that command manually? test -z "/usr/local/share/doc/lame/html" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/share/doc/lame/html";  Also, can you tell me which directories in that path listed exist?

Comment: "/usr/local/share/ " directory is exist

Comment: @Jeremy changed the rights of share directory to 777 , and its done  thank pls update the answer so will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying from my comment

> That is the strangest error... usually
>   it's a sign of forgetting to use "-p"
>   in the mkdir command. Can you try
>   running that command manually? test -z
>   "/usr/local/share/doc/lame/html" ||
>   /bin/mkdir -p
>   "/usr/local/share/doc/lame/html";
>   Also, can you tell me which
>   directories in that path listed exist?

Turns out the problem was a /usr/share with bad permissions.

Answer (score -1):

This question was already answered at [Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50167/why-installing-lame-it-is-getting-failed/50168#50168).

Basically, if the build process complains about a missing X package, you need to install the development package of it. For `libfaac`, this is `libfaac-dev` under Ubuntu.

"No such file or directory" on `/usr/local/share/doc` is not a permission error, it indicates that `/usr/local/share` is missing. A permission error would be "Permission denied".